# Google Pie Chart : Uncaught Error: Container is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, pie-chart, google-pie-chart

I'm trying to display multiple google pie charts on the same page.

I get an `Uncaught Error: Container is not defined` error when doing so. How can I resolve this ?

My code :

```
function drawChart()
{
        var completeness = $(this).attr('data-completeness');

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Nom',    'Valeur'],
            ["Profil rempli à ", completeness],
            ['Manque', 100 - completeness]
        ]);

        var options = {
              ...
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(this);
        chart.draw(data, options);
}

$(function(){
    $('.piechart').each(function(){
        google.load('visualization', '1', {callback : drawChart, 'packages':['corechart']})
    });

});
```

Alternatively, if I iterate in the drawchart function, the output of the piechart gets really weird, it's not an arc anymore but about 5% of an arc (which does not happen if I do not set the completeness dynamically) :

```
function drawChart(elem)
{
    $(elem).each(function(){
        {#var completeness = {{ completeness }};#}
        var completeness = $(this).attr('data-completeness');

        console.log(completeness);

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Nom',    'Valeur'],
            ["Profil rempli à ", completeness],
            ['Manque', 100 - completeness]
        ]);

        var options = {
            backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'},
            pieSliceBorderColor : 'transparent',
            pieHole: 0.8,
            legend: {position: 'top'},
            width: 220,
            height: 220,
            tooltip: {trigger: 'none'},
            pieStartAngle: -90,
            pieSliceTextStyle :{fontsize : 16, color: 'transparent'},
            slices: {
                0: { color: '#09b4ff'},
                1: { color: '#444'}
            },
            chartArea : {width: '90%', height: '90%'}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(this);
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}

$(function(){
    google.load('visualization', '1', {callback : function(){drawChart('.piechart');}, 'packages':['corechart']})
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML code, Which div you posting this graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the document get element id and post like below

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('container'))
```

Make sure you have the same id (container) html div tag, otherwise this will lead error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are calling `var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(this);`

The issue is that you should be passing in an element on the page, but instead you are passing `this` which is likely simply `window`. If you have an element with an id of "container" that you wish to use, you can do this instead:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('container'));
```

You can check out an example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Example)